# Get String[] from SQLite for Multispinner

Tags: android, string, sqlite, spinner

I would like to get a String Array from my database of all contacts (`TABLE_CONTACTS`) to display them in a `MultiSelectionSpinner`.

Is there a way to change this code easy for my purpose?

```
String[] array = { "one", "two", "three" };
spinner = (MultiSelectionSpinner) findViewById(R.id.mySpinner1);
spinner.setItems(array);
```

The `MultiSelectionSpinner` is working with the three numbers, but I fall into despair while trying to get the contacts from my database.

Comment: if you are pulling from a database you should be using a `CursorAdapter`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you must make sure that `TABLE_CONTACTS` has an id column named "_id".

If you have this, then its very simple:

```
Cursor cur= db.rawQuery("select _id, column_to_get_data_from FROM TABLE_CONTACTS", null);
String[] from = new String[]{"column_to_get_data_from"};
int[] to = new int[]{android.R.id.textview_to_put_data_into};
SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, cur, from, to);
```

If you need to bind more fields, you must create your own item.xml spinner item layout xml file to use instead of `android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item` and put the corresponding values on the `from` and `to` arrays.

Then you just add the adapter to the spinner:

```
mAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

Comment: How can I avoid this error in my logcat? java.lang.RuntimeException: setAdapter is not supported by MultiSelectSpinner. It refers to the line where I add the adapter to the spinner  (spinner.setAdapter(mAdapter);)

Comment: You are using a custom spinner with no support for setting an adapter maybe? If so, the above solution wont work obviously.